# What personality and temperament changes should I expect after spaying my dog?

Tags: dogs, behavior, health, psychology

I have an 8 month old Keeshond, who I am planning to spay in June (after her 1st birthday).  What changes can I expect regarding her personality/temperament and why?

There is a lot of info about neutering male dogs and possible personality/temperament changes that result.  However, female dogs seem to be underrepresented in the literature.

**Upvotes for answers which include (or at least link to) the scientific basis for your answer.**

Comment: Scientific basis: Many decades of experience throughout the pet-owning and veterinary communities. That represents a de facto population study, and quite a strong one.  If this question is really trying to ask why not rather than if, the answer would be to look at what the sex hormones actually do in the body, which is also pretty well understood these days. If you want experiential evidence you could survey the many humans who have had ovo-hysterectomies, and can talk about it better than dogs can, though humans also use sex as grooming behavior so it's a bit different.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us what your experience was in this regard

Answer (score 4):

You won't see any changes, it will just prevent her from having behaviors related to being in heat or false pregnancy. However you can see a physical change as they tend to gain weight much easier after being spayed.